Nginx rewrite rule for CSS and JS files
I've been using for a while .htaccess in Apache and now, when using Nginx need to learn new writing.
I've been using in .htaccess:
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.[\d]{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 [L]

It rewrite ...css/style.1234567890.css to css/style.css.
Now, in Nginx I'm trying this:
location ~* \.(js|css)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.\d{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 break;
}

or
location ~ ^(.*)\.\d{10}\.(css|js)$ {
    rewrite ^(.*)\.\d{10}\.(css|js)$ $1.$2 break;
}

But after sudo nginx -t there is still unknown directive "10}\.(css|js)$" error.
What I'm doing wrong?

The following code will perform what you want:
location ~ ^/(.*)\.\d{10}\.(css|js)$ {
    rewrite ^/(.*)\.\d{10}\.(css|js)$ /$1.$2 last;
}

Explanation:
Your second code failed because you used break. This prevents the rewrite from properly continuing the request process. Changing it to last ensures that the rewrite is processed properly and that the request gets re-evaluated with the new URL path.
A few extra notes for others finding this post:

The location part matches URLs with a .css or .js extension and exactly 10 digits between the filename and extension (e.g., style.1234567890.css).
The rewrite rule removes the 10-digit version and keeps the original filename and extension. The last flag ensures that Nginx reprocesses the request after the rewrite.
If you want to extend the pattern for any match between 1 to 10 digits instead of exactly 10, you can replace {10} with {1,10}


I've tried this as well, if you haven't changed anything else, with no result. There should be some syntax problem.
